# Unable to use the get_excerpt function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and php. I am trying to get the excerpt of a post retrieved using foreach in wordpress. I am trying to display all the posts on a page but I dont want to display the whole content I want only excerpt.
I am able to displat the title but unable to get the excerpt.
I have tried: $excerpt = `get_post_excerpt($post)`,`$excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);`, `$excerpt = $post->the_excerpt()`
please also tell me if iam missing some basics.

here is my full code

```html
<?php
 function some_code()  {  
// query
    $query = 'orderby=date&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1';
    $wpq = new WP_Query($query);


    $posts = $wpq->get_posts();
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
  $link = get_permalink($post);
  echo "<a href='$link'><h3>{$post->post_title}</h3></a>";
   $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); 
  echo "$excerpt";
    }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Also. I am using the above function as a shortcode and my shortcode is working fine I had tried displaying "hello world" using echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution compatible with your code would be to use `setup_postdata($post);` inside your `foreach` loop, which makes all the post related data available:

```
$query = 'orderby=date&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1';
$wpq = new WP_Query($query);
$posts = $wpq->get_posts();
foreach($posts as $post)
{
     setup_postdata($post);
     $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);
     echo $excerpt;
}
```

More about `setup_postdata()` can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

Try this also if that doesn't work, I think using a traditional loop instead of `foreach` is a better approach:

```
$query = array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'asc', 'posts_per_page' => '-1');
$wpq = new WP_Query($query);
if($wpq->have_posts()){
    while($wpq->have_posts()){
        $wpq->the_post();
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
```

Or you can use a function called `wp_trim_words`:

`echo wp_trim_words( $post->post_content );`

Comment: Now i am using ` $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post->ID); 
  echo $excerpt;` but still i am getting only titles.

Comment: no, as described in the question I was able to display the Titles but not the excerpt.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($post);`? It's possible that your excerpt is empty.

Comment: setup_postdata($post) helped. when <code>var_dump($post);<code> is used, i get this <pre><code> ["post_title"]=> string(6) "teste2" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(6) "teste2" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-12-06 06:50:01" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-12-06 06:50:01" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) ""......  </code></pre>

Comment: @NilkamalGotarne, awesome. I'm glad it worked. Also the other two solutions should work too.